# ReferenceError: "TextDecoder" is not defined WSO2ESB

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb

I am building a WSO2ESB(5.0.0) service, in which have a script mediator that has some JavaScript code. Using a TextDecoder to convert Hex value to windows-1251 but I get the error:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "TextDecoder" is not defined. (#3) in  at line number 3

Line 3 looks like this:

```
var win1251 = new TextDecoder("windows-1251");
```

Can anyone tell me why that is? Is it supported by wso2esb at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ReferenceError**: The [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

You are using `TextDecoder` which is never declared in your Javascript.

It's same as calling function which doesn't exist, or using variable which doesn't exist.

```
'use strict';
var a = b;
// ReferenceError as b is not declared;
```

You need to check if your Javascript compiler or Browser support `TextDecoder`. As `TextDecoder` is Javascript inbuilt function but not all browser/devises/compiler support this function.

Comment: WSO2 uses the Rhino Javascript engine. Although I could not immediately find if that engine supports TextDecoder.

Comment: Any Javascript compiler who doesn't support `TextDecoder` will treat it as normal class which does not exist, thus I can assume that version of Rhino Javascript Engine you are using doesn't support `TextDecoder`. To check you can create class `TextDecoder` and it's constructor will just `console.log` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Changing node version from 10 to 12 worked for me.

```
nvm use 12
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).